# androidx media router and media session

Tags: android, androidx, android-mediasession, mediasession, mediarouter

I'm going through `MediaRouter` documentation:
https://developer.android.com/media/routing/mediarouter

and it looks like I must use the media router button in order to connect and create a media session.

but, if I already have the remote device ip, can I create a media route and a media session, and connect to the device, just by its' ip, without using the media router button?
if so, what are the steps I need to do?

thanks